# Cube Mesh Basic Effect Missing Contains Geometry That Is Missing Coordinates For Channel 0 XNA

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, blender, mesh

I've just started using Blender in conjuction with **XNA 4.0** to make a 3D game.  However, I ran into an issue early on.  When I loaded a cube model (the one that blender starts with) with a texture in `Visual Studio`, it gave an error when I tried to build.  I've written no code whatsoever about the model and I just started the program.  The Error List said

**"The mesh "Cube", using BasicEffect, contains geometry that is missing texture coordinates for channel 0."**
First, I am using `.fbx` files I've exported out.  Should I get something to export `.x` files from blender?  Why did this message pop up, and how do I fix it?  Do I have to write code to initialize something before I just compile? If so, what?

Thanks

Comment: So I haven't really used Blender at all, so I might be wrong, but based on the error, it sounds like the cube is using a texture that you're not providing XNA. But I could be wrong

Comment: Well, I do have the texture loaded in XNA, yet I think it's refering to the vertices of the models, and its data about the texture coordinates.  At least thats what I understand from what I read.  The only thing is, I dont know how to set those texture coordinates.

Comment: Did you use the XNA option when exporting your model?

Comment: @NeilKnight, how exactly do you do that?

Comment: @Mapcat1118, Blender has an option http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cR0EAk6IQ6Y/TtdUrKPNn7I/AAAAAAAAAeM/Hh4z_2mdR1M/s1600/FBXxnastrictoptions260a2011-11-30.jpg

Comment: @NeilKnight is that an older version of Blender on that website?  I have a few more options, but I don't see that.

Comment: @Mapcat1118: what version of Blender are you using?